# Bicep roleAssignments/write permission error when assigning a role to Keyvault

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep, azure-rbac

I am using GitHub Actions to deploy via Bicep:

```
- name: Login
  uses: azure/login@v1
  with:
    creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        
- name: Deploy Bicep file
  uses: azure/arm-deploy@v1
  with:
    scope: subscription
    subscriptionId: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS_subscriptionId }}
    region: ${{ env.DEPLOY_REGION }}
    template: ${{ env.BICEP_ENTRY_FILE }}
    parameters: parameters.${{ inputs.selectedEnvironment }}.json
```

I have used a contributor access for my `AZURE_CREDENTIALS` based on the output of the next command:

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --n infra-bicep --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/my-subscription-guid --sdk-auth`

I am using Azure Keyvault with **RBAC**. This Bicep has worked fine until I tried to give an Azure Web App a keyvault read access to the Keyvault as such:

```
var kvSecretsUser = '4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6'
var kvSecretsUserRole = subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', kvSecretsUser)
resource kx_webapp_roleAssignments 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2022-04-01' = {
  name: 'kv-webapp-roleAssignments'
  scope: kv
  properties: {
    principalId: webappPrincipleId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
    roleDefinitionId: kvSecretsUserRole
  }
}
```

Then I was hit with the following error:

```
'Authorization failed for template resource 'kv-webapp-roleAssignments' 
of type 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments'. 
The client 'guid-value' with object id 'guid-value' does not have permission to perform action 
'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' at scope
 '/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/rg-x/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/
kv-x/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/kv-webapp-roleAssignments'.'
```

What are the total minimal needed permissions and what should my `az ad sp create-for-rbac` statement(s) be and are there any other steps I need to do to assign role permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To assign RBAC roles, you need to have either **User Access
> Administrator** or **Owner** role that includes below permission:
> `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`

With **Contributor** role, you cannot assign RBAC roles to Azure resources. To confirm that, you can check this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor).

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I used the same command and created one service principal with **Contributor** role as below:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --n infra-bicep --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/my-subscription-guid --sdk-auth
```

**Response:**

[image]

I generated one **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <clientID from above response>
client_secret: <clientSecret from above response>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to assign **Key Vault Secrets User** role with below API call, I got **same error** as you like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/d689e7fb-47d7-4fc3-b0db-xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2022-04-01
{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/d689e7fb-47d7-4fc3-b0db-xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6",
    "principalId": "456c2d5f-12e7-4448-88ba-xxxxxxxxx",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, create a service principal with either **User Access Administrator** or **Owner** role.

In my case, I created a service principal with **Owner** role like below:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --n infra-bicep-owner --role owner --scopes /subscriptions/my-subscription-guid --sdk-auth
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** again via Postman by replacing `clientId` and `clientSecret` values like below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: <clientID from above response>
client_secret: <clientSecret from above response>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to assign **Key Vault Secrets User** role with below API call, I got **response** successfully like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/d689e7fb-47d7-4fc3-b0db-xxxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2022-04-01
{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/d689e7fb-47d7-4fc3-b0db-xxxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/4633458b-17de-408a-b874-0445c86b69e6",
    "principalId": "456c2d5f-12e7-4448-88ba-xxxxxxxxx",
    "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

#### UPDATE:

Considering least privileges principle, you need to create **custom RBAC role** instead of assigning **`Owner`** role.

To create custom RBAC role, follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Your Subscription -> Access control (IAM) -> Add -> Add custom role***

[image]

Fill the details with *name* and *description*, make sure to select **Contributor** role after choosing `Clone a role` like below:

[image]

Now, remove below permission from **NotAction** `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write`

[image]

Now, add `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission in **Action**:

[image]

Now, click on **Create** like below:

[image]

You can create service principal with above **custom role** using this command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --n infra_bicep_custom_role --role 'Custom Contributor' --scopes /subscriptions/my-subscription-guid --sdk-auth
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reproduce. However, it is missing an important part of my question which is **minimal** which I trust **owner** is too much for it as it doesn't follow the least privileges principle. Can I "append" the User Access Administrator to the Contributor role?

Comment: If that's the case, you can create **custom** RBAC role by adding `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` permission along with Contributor permissions.

Comment: I did this. I have created a custom role on the subscription level, started from `contributer` added `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write` , then I have to remove the `Microsoft.Authorization/*/write` and `Microsoft.Authorization/*/read` `NoAction` which came from `contributor`. Do you want to update your answer with these actions so I can mark it? This will help future generations.

Comment: Removing the two permissions of the No Action BUT adding Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write . I think you have just removed the two without adding this permission. Only last note, the RBAC command should be `az ad sp create-for-rbac --n infra-bicep-owner --role **[Your Custom Roles]** --scopes /subscriptions/my-subscription-guid --sdk-auth`